# Firebase Jira integration error - Unable to reach the Jira instance

Tags: android, firebase, jira

In Firebase in the project setting's integrations tab, it asks to enter your Jira project URL. Firebase docs say it should be in the format:
https://[workspace-name].atlassian.net/projects/[project-key]

When I'm in Jira, and click on the project I want to connect, it opens automatically to the trello board section I connected, and the url I have from the browser is:
https://[workspace-name].atlassian.net/jira/software/projects/[project-key]/boards/1 
I get the error 'Unexpected project URL format'

So when I truncate the URL so it will look more like the doc's format to:
https://[workspace-name].atlassian.net/jira/software/projects/[project-key]
I get the error: Unable to reach the Jira instance (also note the word 'software' that differs from the Firebase docs expectation)

Also when I try and use the truncated URL in the browser it gives me 404 error, indicating this is NOT the correct URL.
Why can't I get to the pure project URL by clicking on my Jira project?

Comment: Tried with something like this: `https://[WORKSPACE].atlassian.net/projects/[PROJECT-KEY]/` ? Just replace the project key with the string you find in Jira administration

Comment: Wow thank you! Can't believe it worked hahaha. write it up as an answer and I'll upvote

Comment: Done, maybe it will help someone else :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Jira Cloud you can simply go with this URL:

https://[WORKSPACE].atlassian.net/projects/[PROJECT-KEY]/

Where `PROJECT-KEY` can be found in the Jira administration panel

Answer (score 1):

Step 1) Get your atlassian api key from here:

https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens

Step 2) Select the desired project from your jira dashboard and copy your jira project key from here:

https://[YOUR ATLASSIAN SERVER]/jira/software/projects/[PROJECT YOU WANT TO INTEGRATE]/settings/details

Step 3) Finally then put your jira project url into firebase console ([https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/[YOUR](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/%5BYOUR) FIREBASE PROJECT]/settings/integrations/jira?pli=1) like this format:

https://[WORKSPACE].atlassian.net/projects/[PROJECT-KEY]

Step 4) Simply hit **Next** button.

Step 5) Authenticate with your jira login email and api key.

Happy integratiion :)